# How can I load PyTorch transforms from a yaml configuration file?

Tags: pytorch

I need to assess how well different combinations of PyTorch augmentations/transforms work to improve the generalization ability of my model. For example, I want to see if RandomResizeCrop and RandomAffine work better separately or if I combine them.

If I want to change the parameters of RandomResizeCrop, I could just have a few lines of configuration in my YAML file and load them. But is there a way to load a `transforms.Compose` object from a YAML file? If a transform exists in the YAML file, it's loaded and if it doesn't exist it's simply not part of that particular run.

If such a thing is possible, is it possible for a human to edit such YAML files easily to set up different experiment configurations?